# Using an external webcam instead of the hardware camera

Tags: android, android-camera

Now I use this to take photo

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 1);
```

Is there a method to use an external webcam, connected via USB, instead of hardware camera?

Answer (score 0):

Not with `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`. You are asking one of hundreds of possible camera apps to take a picture on your app's behalf. Many of those camera apps will have no support for a USB-based webcam.

My understanding is that the native Camera2 API on Android has some support for external cameras, though I do not know the details, and the Camera2 API is *very* complicated.